# Accessibility vs Disabilities tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We've got two tags: [accessibility](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility) and [disabilities](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disabilities). Personally I don't see the need for two and think [disabilities](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disabilities) should be made a synonym of [accessibility](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility)

Disabilities isn't a very common tag and I really can't imagine a question meaningfully differentiating the two tags--for purpose of design, accessibility is pretty much what we're talking about when designing generally or specifically for any form of disability.

Objections, suggestions?

Comment: Agreed, lets synonyme disability to accessibility!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No apparent objections, went and added the synonym.